# update elastic-search document with the same ID

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

everyone. I'm new in elk and I have a question about logstash.
I have some services and each one has 4 or 6 logs; it means a doc in elastic may has 4 or 6 logs.
I want to read these logs and if they have the same id, put them in one elastic doc.
I must specify that all of the logs have a unique "id" and each request and every log that refers to that request has the same id. each log has a specific type.
I want to put together every log that has the same id and type; like this:

```
    {
      "_id":"123",
      "Type1":{},
      "Type2":[{},{}],
      "Type3":[{},{}],
      "Type4":{}
    }
```

Every log for the same requset:
Some of them must be in the same group. because their type are the same. look example above. Type2 is Json Array and has 2 jsons. I want to use logstash to read every log and have them classified.
Imagine that our doc is like bellow JSON at the moment:

```
    {
      "_id": "123",
      "Type1":{},
      "Type2":[{},{}],
      "Type3":{}
    }
```

now a new log arrives, with id 123 and it's type is Type4. The doc must update like this:

```
    {
      "_id": "123",
      "Type1":{},
      "Type2":[{},{}],
      "Type3":{},
      "Type4":{}
    }
```

again, I have new log with id, 123 and type, Type3. the doc update like this:

```
    {
      "_id": "123",
      "Type1":{},
      "Type2":[{},{}],
      "Type3":[{},{}],
      "Type4":{}
    }
```

I tried with script, but I didn't succeed. :

```
    {
      "id": 1,
        "Type2": {}
    }
```

The script is:

```
input {
    stdin {
        codec => json_lines
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"]
      index => "ss"
      document_id => "%{requestId}"
      action => "update" # update if possible instead of overwriting 
      document_type => "_doc"
      script_lang => "painless"
      scripted_upsert => true
      script_type => "inline"
      script => 'if (ctx._source.Type3 == null) { ctx._source.Type3 = new ArrayList() } if(!ctx._source.Type3.contains("%{Type3}")) { ctx._source.Type3.add("%{Type3}")}'
    }
}
```

now my problem is this script format just one type; if it works for multiple types, what would it look like?
there is one more problem. I have some logs that they don't have an id, or they have an id, but don't have a type. I want to have these logs in the elastic, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on [aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) filter plugin for logstash. Or as you mentioned if some of the logs don't have an id, then you can use [fingerprint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-fingerprint.html) filter plugin to create an id, which you can use to update document in elasticsearch.
E.g:

```
input {
    stdin {
        codec => json_lines
    }
}
filter {
  fingerprint {
     source => "message"
     target => "[@metadata][id]"
     method => "MURMUR3"
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"]
      index => "ss"
      document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}"
      action => "update" # update if possible instead of overwriting
    }
}
```